# how to use custom ssh keys with stash (cli) tools?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket-server

I just found Atlassians nifty stash command line tools. Cool. Since I use custom ssh keys I configure them in ~/.ssh thusly:

```
Host bb
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    user git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/custom_key
```

When I tried to issue a pull request with the stash tool (on cli) I got the following message:

> error: Repository does not seem to be hosted in Stash; Remote url: bb:hippeelee/land-of-lisp-for-clojure.

I ran stash configure but it didn't offer an option to set up my ssh preferences. Anyone know of a way to use custom ssh keys with the Atlassian stash cli tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stash developer here.

[Looks like](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-command-line-tools/src/4c307ae8d503fc2a11626cfa236476ec0e6b479e/lib/atlassian/stash/repo_info.rb?at=master#cl-41) the tool uses regex to match against the URL. In particular it's expecting two slashes - the ':' is throwing it off, and it needs to end in '.git'. What happens if you try "ssh://bb/hippeelee/land-of-lisp-for-clojure.git"?

EDIT: Also, it's worth pointing out that Stash command line tools don't work with Bitbucket. We currently have different APIs.